# Why does `std.meta.stringToEnum` using identical input fail in one context but not another?

Tags: zig

I'm playing around with zig trying to make a toy comptime assembler, using  `std.meta.stringToEnum` which appears to be succeeding in one context while failing in another, *seemingly* with identical inputs. See the following example, where "test a" fails but "test b" succeeds.

```
const std = @import("std");

const Mnemonic = enum { ADC, SBC, AND };

fn readMnemonic(comptime input: []const u8) struct { Mnemonic, []const u8 } {
    const mnemonic = std.meta.stringToEnum(Mnemonic, input[0..3]) orelse {
        @compileError("Invalid mnemonic encountered: " ++ input[0..3]);
    };

    return .{ mnemonic, input[3..] };
}

test "test a" {
    const mnemonic = readMnemonic("ADCBE");
    try std.testing.expectEqual(Mnemonic.ADC, mnemonic.@"0");
}

test "test b" {
    const mnemonic = std.meta.stringToEnum(Mnemonic, "ADCBE"[0..3]) orelse {
        std.debug.panic("conversion failed", .{});
    };
    try std.testing.expectEqual(Mnemonic.ADC, mnemonic);
}
```

In "test a", `stringToEnum` is called in `readMnemonic`, while it's being called directly in "test b". *As far as I can tell*, the value supplied to `stringToEnum` should be identical in both places. Is there some subtle difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "test a", invoke `readMnemonic` as:

```
const mnemonic = comptime readMnemonic("ADCBE");
```

and the test passes. Alternatively, you can `comptime` invoke `std.meta.stringToEnum` in `readMnemonic`, i.e.

```
const mnemonic = comptime std.meta.stringToEnum ...
```

Comptime interactions with runtime function invocations can be a bit strange.